# View local saved/stopped instances of docker images

Tags: docker

There is

```
docker images
```

to show locally saved `images`  and

```
  docker ps
```

to show `running` docker images

How do we view the locally saved/stopped *instances* of images?  For example when I do

```
 docker start *instance_name*
```

it does start the docker *instance_name*

But how do to view  all locally saved instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

```
  docker ps -a
```

Lists *all* docker instances including the stopped ones.